# Android autocomplete textview in thread not working

Tags: android, multithreading, autocomplete, adapter

I am working with an autocomplete textview but when i try to do it in a thread its not working . Here is my code

```
 Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    sleep(1000);

            mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            PopulatePeopleList();
            mAdapternew = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mPeopleList,
                    R.layout.rowone, new String[] { "Name", "Phone" },
                    new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontnumber });
            atvPlaces.setAdapter(mAdapternew);
            atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);

   }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

in PopulatePeopleList(); i'm getting all my contacts. AutocompleteTextView working fine if i am not using in a listview , but it is hanging my layout then.

Comment: it should crash, what does *but it is hanging my layout then* mean ?

Comment: use runOnUIThread to filter instead of Thread.

Comment: @Blackbelt what should i do then?

Comment: Use AsyncTask instead http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. and update your list in onPostExecute method.

Comment: @Mr.smith i used AsyncTask but its hanging layout after some time

Answer (score 0):

The changes to the UI must go on the main thread (UI thread), so you should either execute all the lines after `PopulatePeopleList()` in the UI thread with something like:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    mAdapternew = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
      mPeopleList,
      R.layout.rowone, new String[] { "Name", "Phone" },
      new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontnumber });
    atvPlaces.setAdapter(mAdapternew);
    atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);
  }
});
```

or you could use an AsyncTask (approach that I prefer as I find more intuitive) where you put the changes to the UI in the `onPostExecute()` and the `PopulatePeopleList()` on the `doInBackground()`

Comment: But exception getting in doinBackground if i use AsyncTask